# Inserting data to multiple tables with one-many-relationship in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, for-loop, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I have 3 tables with one-to-many relationship to each of them:
1  parent -> 2 children
2 children each has 3 grandchildren which makes
1 parent -> 6 grandchildren

How do I create 6 Grandchildren differentiate by their respective Children when I create 2 Children under 1 Parent? Here's an illustration of what I want in my database when I key in 1 Parent object:

[image]

Below is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))

    parents_info = db.relationship('Children', backref='parents')

class Children(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    asset_amount = db.Column(db.Integer())

    parents_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parents.id'))

    children_info = db.relationship('Grandchildren', backref='child')

class Grandchildren(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    gender = db.Column(db.String(120))

    children_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('children.id'))
```

**build_db.py**

```
def build_sample_db():
    db.create_all()

    # Add to Parent table
    parent = Parent()
    parent.name = "Jack Sparrow"

    db.session.add(parent)

    # Add to Children table
    children_name = ['Hulk','Ironman']
    amount = ['300','500000']

    children_list = []
    for i in range(len(fraudster_name)):
        children = Children()
        children.name = children_name[i]
        children.asset_amount = amount[i]
        children.parents = parent

        db.session.add(children)


    ### Correct me if I'm wrong at formatting the list
    grandchildren_name = [['Hulk_one', 'Hulk_two', 'Hulk_three'], ['Ironman_one', 'Ironman_two', 'Ironman_three']]
    gender = [['female','female','male'], ['female','male','male']]
    ### How do I loop through my grandchildren to put into database

    db.session.commit() 
    return
```

Anyone please enlighten me on the looping part, or if I code it wrongly. I could have imagine things will be more complicated if there are multiple columns in *Grandchildren* table. Your help is greatly appreciated!